# Transferring android app with subscription to another account is still not possible?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I want to transfer my app with subscriptions to another company, but it seems that it was not possible before, and the document of google is vague.

Does anyone know if it is still not possible or is there any good way to do that like transferring the developer account itself?

[Transferring android app with subscription to another account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26914800/transferring-android-app-with-subscription-to-another-account)

[Android Developer Console - Change app owner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176717/android-developer-console-change-app-owner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is allowed nowadays! You can transfer apps with in-app subsriptions to a new developer account. And you need pay extra attention to linked project if you used Play Developer APIs to verify the purchases or used other integrated services. After the transfering process, the renewal orders will be visible in the Play Console under the new developer account while the previous orders will only be visible under your current account.

Comment: Thanks!  The Google support also confirmed it to me that it is possible now!

Comment: @NonUmemoto, so how is your transfer went? Here is what worries me: after an app is transferred, will active subscriptions continue to review automatically or users has to do some manual actions?

Comment: @jackes, the active subscriptions will be renewed automatically without requiring any user actions.