# Playstore: how to transfer one app to another developer account?

Tags: android, transfer

I have a developer account.(Let's call Account A or A)
and one customer wants to buy two of my apps, and he already made an account as well(Let's call Account B or B).

Account A has 5 apps, and Account B has nothing. Right now, I'd like to transfer 2 apps from A to B.

The only way that was referred on the help center was to move whole apps I published with A to B, and if I do that, A account will be closed after transfer, but I don't wanna do that.
Any ideas?

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176717/android-developer-console-change-app-owner

Comment: It seems that you can select transfered apps as of [the official explanation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ok, I understand that I can just transfer some of my apps to another account. Is my Account A going to be closed and unable to be used as developer account after only tranferring some of my apps to another account?

Comment: I came across this question while searching for an answer. I wonder if one looses all the SEO and other work done in promoting the app if you change the account of an app?