# How to Change Play Store Console Account Email Id

Tags: android

By mistake I created an account in Google Play store Developer Console using my personal mail Id (say A@gmail.com) but I want to access through other mail id that i created specially for Google Play Store Developer Console access(say B@gmail.com). How to do so?

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691?hl=en

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16176717/5180017) also.

Comment: Thank you . This was of great help.

Answer (score 5):

From your description, it seems the links posted in the comments are the only ways of achieving your goal here.  Your options are one of the following:

1. Add **B@gmail.com** as a developer following the [**Add developer account users & manage permissions**](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691) article.
2. Transfer ownership to **B@gmail.com** following the [**Transfers apps to a different developer account**](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247) article.